# Check if subdomain exist via middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I want to check if a subdomain exists before redirecting a user to the login form. So I want to apply the "website" middleware before the "auth" middleware.

**web.php:**

```php
Route::domain('{website}.localhost')->middleware(['website', 'auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    //others routes
});
```

**website middleware:**

```php
if(Website::where('domain_name', $request->route('website'))->exists())
{
    return $next($request);
}
else
{
    abort(404);
}
```

If I try to go to http://fakedomain.localhost I am redirected to the login form rather than getting a 404.

**edit 1:**
I registered my middleware in the kernel.php

Comment: You Add in Kernel middleware name ?

Comment: @Arthur oc my middleware is in Kernel.php

Comment: the fakedomain is exist?

Comment: @ZeroOne no, so I should get a 404. Instead I am redirected to the login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to adjust the middleware priorities so it will run this middleware before 'auth'. You can statically define the middleware priority list (which is already defined on the base `Illuminate\Http\Kernel`) or you can dynamically prepend to the middleware priority list in a Service Provider.

In a Service Provider's `boot` method:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Contracts\Kernel;

public function boot()
{
    $this->app[Kernel::class]->prependToMiddlewarePriority(YourMiddleware::class);
}
```

Or you can statically define the list in your `App\Http\Kernel`:

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class,

    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ...
];
```

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Middleware - Registering Middleware -Sorting Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#sorting-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

open Kernel.php
add in `$routeMiddleware`  array your Middleware

```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'website' => YourMiddlewareClass::class
   ];
```